# How to integrate Sublime Text with GitHub?

Tags: git, github, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I thought it would be perfect if ST would have a plugin for syncing repo with the one on GitHub account, but I can't find such a thing.

There is Github Tools and sublime-github but they don't provide `commit` or `push` commands.

I can always use GitHub's app for syncing but plugin is more convenient, since it can be assigned to ST's hotkeys.

Comment: A simple web search for "sublime text git plugin" shows several options. What's wrong with any of those?

Comment: it appears I've got the wrong idea - actually, I can set my account in git and use ST plugin called "git", github apps are not necessary

Comment: GitHub is a commercial service (and series of optional applications) that is built on an open source program called Git. In general, standard Git tools work with GitHub. GitHub-specific tools may be required to interact with GitHub-specific features like their wiki and issue tracker.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are [numerous `git` plugins](https://sublime.wbond.net/search/git) available via [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net), so all you have to do is browse through them, read the READMEs, and decide if you want to try it out. I use [`SideBarGit`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SideBarGit) (along with [`SideBarEnhancements`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SideBarEnhancements)), which allows you to right-click on a file in your project and get access to the whole array of `git`-related tasks, from `Add & Commit & Push` to `Branch` to `Clone` to `Diff` and more. Another popular tool is [`Git`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Git), which provides essentially the same options as `SideBarGit`, just in a menu off `Tools` instead.

[`SublimeGit`](https://sublimegit.net/) is a free-to-try, € 10 to buy commercial plugin (available through Package Control) that looks like it's very full-featured, allowing you to do just about anything related to git. It includes a number of syntax definitions for editing commit messages, looking at diffs, comparing branches, etc., and judging by its popularity (it's one of the Top 100 at Package Control) a lot of people seem to like it. But, it's not open-source, and costs extra money to use long-term.

Any of these will work with Github, Bitbucket, or any other public or private repo that uses the `git` protocol. Try them out, and see what works for you.

Comment: Looks like SideBarGit is dead. Have you found anything better @MattDMo

Comment: @getthemike it's not dead, it's just not available on Package Control anymore. You'll have to install manually from [Github](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarGit) instead. As far as I know, it's been removed from PC because the author is a pissy little whiner who doesn't like PC's rule that packages follow sane versioning rules, so he turned his back on literally hundreds of thousands of users (he's written a lot of popular plugins) and removed them from PC, which means they'll no longer be automatically updated - you have to watch the individual repos yourself.

Answer (score 12):

## 13  March  2019 - SublimeMerge was released

You can use [SublimeMerge](https://www.sublimemerge.com/), which was created by the same people, who wrote SublimeText - so you can expect compatibility and updates as long as SublimeText is as popular as it is.

SublimeText version 3.2 has GitIntegration as a new feature. Here is some details from changelog:

- Files and folders in the sidebar will now display badges to indicate Git status
- Ignored files and folders are visually de-emphasized
- The current Git branch and number of modifications is displayed in the status bar
- Commands have been added to open a repository, see file or folder history, or blame a file in Sublime Merge
- Themes may customize the display of sidebar badges and status bar information
- The setting show_git_status allows disabling Git integration
- All file reads are done through a custom, high-performance Git library written for Sublime Merge
- [Read the documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/git_integration.html)

Answer (score 1):

All you need are the extensions '**Git**', '**Git Gutter**', and '**Sublimerge**'

**Git:** I use it to open git gui and perform all the other git operations right inside Sublime Text.

**Git Gutter** I use this to display the new changes that are not committed yet on the current working file.

**Sublimerge** I use this to compare the current working file with any previous revisions of the same file

Answer (score 0):

Via [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/), you can install [sublime-github](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/sublime-github).
It's simple and works fine for me.

Comment: did you read the question ? "There is Github Tools and sublime-github but they don't provide commit or push commands" I'm suprised that this answer is still here and was edited btw

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using [**Sublime Merge**](https://www.sublimemerge.com/), [mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55145699/6309), you can invoke it directly with `git difftool` now.

With Git 2.22 (Q2 2019), that will be easier, since the configuration will be done for you, and "`git mergetool`" learned to offer Sublime Merge (`smerge`) as one of its backends.

As commented in [SublimeTextIssues/Merge issue 19](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Merge/issues/19#issuecomment-483895235):

Usage:

```
git config --global merge.tool smerge
```

and then just `git mergetool` or `git difftool`.

See [commit f57b2ae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f57b2ae348950c0048f0091093f9d1e095d11d08), [commit eb12adc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb12adc74cf22add318f884072be2071d181abaa) (04 Apr 2019) by [David Aguilar (`davvid`)](https://github.com/davvid).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5116eab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5116eab70bf8a0c8b1c29a09c4b932c4d1cf2701), 22 Apr 2019)</sup>

> ### `mergetools`: add support for `smerge` (Sublime Merge)
>
> Teach `difftool` and `mergetool` about the Sublime Merge "`smerge`" command.

Git now has a [`mergetools/smerge`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/eb12adc74cf22add318f884072be2071d181abaa/mergetools/smerge) file with:

> ```
> diff_cmd () {
>     "$merge_tool_path" mergetool "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" -o "$MERGED"
> }
>
> merge_cmd () {
>     if $base_present
>     then
>         "$merge_tool_path" mergetool "$BASE" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" -o "$MERGED"
>     else
>         "$merge_tool_path" mergetool "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" -o "$MERGED"
>     fi
> }
> ```

Again: the configuration is done for you.

Answer (score 0):

copy the link of the Github repo and past it in the URL.

if not happens / error, delete the passwords from the credential manager of your PC