# Managing Git or bitbucket repositories through Sublime text

Tags: git, push, bitbucket, sublimetext

Hi team was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction, I wanted to know is there a plugin or some documentation on how to use my sublime text editor to pull and push my changes to repositories without leaving my sublime text editor?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to find some good resources, just access package control to install them.

1) **sublime-github** - free
2) **SideBarGit** - free
3) **SublimeGit** - € 10

Check out **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23716909/how-to-integrate-sublime-text-with-github)** post to view more in detail about sublime and git

Comment: IMHO The answer is not bitbucket specific.Sublime has a good bunch of git/gist features and no bitbucket's