# Managing GitHub inside Sublime Text

Tags: github, sublimetext3

I was wondering if there are any plugins that are available to manage GitHub repo right inside of Sublime Text? For example, I know that if I add an issue number to my commit message, it will close the GitHub issue. But is there a way to create a GitHub issue, or view GitHub issues right inside Sublime Text? Would be great to know this and any other features that would be available for integration of GitHub with Sublime.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23717489/3275967.

I personally use [Git](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git/wiki), while @MattDMo apparently uses [SideBarGit](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SideBarGit), and helpfully provides a nice overview of [Git-related packages](https://packagecontrol.io/search/git) for Sublime.

However, neither package seems to support Github issues. So if you do a search for 'Github' in packagecontrol, you get (among many others)

- [Github Tools for Sublime Text](https://github.com/temochka/sublime-text-2-github-tools), which will redirect you to the Github webpage for issues, and
- [GitSavvy](https://github.com/divmain/GitSavvy), which apparently will give you a list of issues to choose from when you commit with an issue number (see [the docs](https://github.com/divmain/GitSavvy/blob/master/docs/github.md#issues-integration)).